# jquery-ui draggable widget do not work well in firefox on scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, frontend

hi i encounter the issue in firefox here is the snippet:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

```css
#draggable{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}

.test1{
 border:1px solid red;
 width:150px;
 height:120px;
 word-break:break-all;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
 <div class="test1">
  asdasdasdasdasdddasdasdasdasdasd
 dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd asdasdasdddddddddddddddddddasdasdsdsdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdsddddddddddddddddddddddd
 </div>
</div>
```

1 open it in firefox(my version is 33.1.1)
2 click the scrollbar of ".test1" div,then scroll
3 the issue is when you click the scrollbar and slide,the whole content will move.

it works well in IE/chrome.
what is the reason cause the problem?

Comment: Do you get a solution for this issue?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on Mac OS (which has floating scrollbars that on the right over the scrollable content, like on iOS or Android). It seems like both Mac OS and Firefox fire events under the scrollbar when they're not supposed to for some reason.

Comment: @MohaideenIsmail You shouldn't be making duplicates. Instead try improving the original question - You can go to the fiddle, add the necessary code here, and then post a proper link to the fiddle etc... or if you are keen at getting a solution immediately, put a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try this workaround:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.search('Firefox') !== -1) {
    $('#draggable').draggable({
        handle: ':not(.test1)'
    });
} else {
    $('#draggable').draggable();
}
```